# How can I iterate through lines of a remote file in shell using cURL?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I understand how to iterate through lines in a local file. But how about a remote file?

```
while read NAME
do
    echo "$NAME"
done < curl -sL 'http://mylistofnames.com/list.html
```

If this were local, I would replace the last line with `done < names.txt`. I'm stuck on remote.

Answer (score 5):

Put the curl command in a [bash process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
while read NAME
do
    echo "$NAME"
done < <(curl -sL 'http://mylistofnames.com/list.html')
```

Piping works as well, but if variables are set in the while loop and they are needed outside the scope of the while loop then this solution becomes necessary.

Comment: Can you check your syntax for me?  Piping indeed worked, but I would like to access variables set within the loop outside of the loop. I keep getting unexpected token errors with the variations I'm trying. Latest attempt: `done < $(curl -sL http://domain.com/list.html)`

Comment: @Ryan You have an extra `$` before the process substitution. `$(...)` is command substitution.

Comment: I know, I was getting unexpected token errors with the `<` so I was experimenting. Either way it's not working for me.

Comment: Doh! I had `#!/bin/sh` at the top instead of `#!/bin/bash`. All better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the output:

```
curl -sL 'http://mylistofnames.com/list.html' | while read NAME
    do echo "$NAME"
done
```

With process substitution:

```
while read NAME
    do echo "$NAME"
done < <(curl -sL 'http://mylistofnames.com/list.html')
```

Comment: Piping worked. Thanks. Though I'm now looking to get process substitution working so I can access the variables outside of the loop.

Comment: Added the process substitution version

Comment: Interesting. So that is the correct syntax.  But I keep getting `syntax error near unexpected token `<'` errors.

Comment: What version of bash are you running? It might not have process substitution.

Comment: Doh! I had `#!/bin/sh` at the top instead of `#!/bin/bash`. All better. Thanks again.